# Insert data into BigQuery separate tables from same file with different schema using Dataflow(Apache Beam) using side output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, audit-logging

I have this requirement where in I need to develop a Audit Mechanism. For Example there is a JSON file name emp.json:

```
{
    "magic": "atMSG",
    "type": "DT",
    "headers": null,
    "messageschemaid": null,
    "messageschema": null,
    "message": {
        "data": {
            "ID": "data_in_quotes",
            "NAME": "data_in_quotes",
            "SALARY": "data_in_quotes"
        },
        "beforeData": null,
        "headers": {
            "operation": "INSERT",
            "changeSequence": "20200822230048000000000017887787417",
            "timestamp": "2020-08-22T23:00:48.000",
            "transactionId": "some_id"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to insert the data into Bigquery table first:
Staging.emp

ID, NAME, SALARY

1, ABC, 20000

2, XYZ, 30000

I also need to insert the ID, timestamp(Loading timestamp) and filename into a separate table:
misc-dataset.Audit_table

ID, TIMESTAMP,  FILENAME

1, 28-08-2020 22:55, emp.json

2, 28-08-2020 22:55, emp.json

As of now I am inserting into file to test it. if this is solved I will use

```
| "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                        "{0}:{1}.emp_data".format(projectId, datasetId),
                        schema=table_schema,
                        #write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                        )
```

I am unable to get that using side output, using the below code.

```
class InsertIntoBQAndAudit(beam.DoFn):
    
    def process(self, element):
        norm = json_normalize(json.loads(element), max_level=1)
        l = norm["message.data"]
        return l
    
    def process(self, element):
        norm1 = json_normalize(json.loads(element), max_level=1)
        l1 = norm1["message.data"]
        
        l1['ID']
        l1['TIMESTAMP':datetime.now()]
        l1.[m.metadata_list for m in gcs.match(['gs://ti-project-1/emp*'])]
        return [beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('Audit', l1)]

options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

data_from_source = (p
                    | "READ FROM JSON" >> ReadFromText("gs://ti-project-1/input/bill_document_prod_data_sample_records")
                     | "Send to Different Tags" >> beam.ParDo(InsertIntoBQAndAudit()).with_outputs('Audit', main='Load')
                   )

Audit_col = data_from_source.Audit
Load_col = data_from_source.Load

Load_col | "Write to Actual Table" >> WriteToText("gs://ti-project-1/output/data_output")
Audit_col | "Write to Audit Table" >> WriteToText("gs://ti-project-1/misc-temp/audit_out")

p.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DoFn cannot have two process methods. Instead, create two separate DoFns and apply each to the same PCollection, e.g.

```
class Audit(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, l1)
    l1['ID']
    l1['TIMESTAMP':datetime.now()]
    # This line above seems to have gotten mangled in transit...
    l1 = [m.metadata_list for m in gcs.match(['gs://ti-project-1/emp*'])]
    yield l1

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
  data_from_source = p | "READ FROM JSON" >> ReadFromText("gs://...")
  parsed_data = data_from_source | beam.Map(
      lambda element: json_normalize(json.loads(element), max_level=1)["message.data"])
  
  Load_col = parsed_data
  Audit_col = parsed_data | beam.ParDo(Audit)
  ...
```

You could use a multi-output DoFn for this, which would look like

```
class ParseAndAudit(beam.DoFn):
    
    def process(self, element):
        norm = json_normalize(json.loads(element), max_level=1)
        l = norm["message.data"]
        yield l  # emit the main output
    
        # continue in the same process method
        l1 = l
        
        l1['ID']
        l1['TIMESTAMP':datetime.now()]
        l1.[m.metadata_list for m in gcs.match(['gs://ti-project-1/emp*'])]
        yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('Audit', l1)
```

and then use it as you ahve above, but that's probably more complicated to write and maintain.

Comment: Hi @robertwb, the first solution works like a charm. Second one still doesn't, its astonishing that the concept of side output is not working. Basically my try was to get a side output. But Thank you very much for the solution. I have more such problems in GCP dataflow, can I please contact you via email/linkedln to learn more please.

Comment: Side outputs should work, though I admit that they're trickier to get right.

Comment: I answer questions here on a best-effort basis where they can benefit everyone (and prefer not to give out my private info).